# How to control-click items using Geb?

Tags: java, groovy, webdriver, geb

I'm working with Geb on automating testing of a web application that uses ExtJS to present much of its UI.  I'm in a situation where I need to ctrl-click several ExtJS-generated table cells representing 'categories'.  How do I use Geb to ctrl-click these things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do control-clicking I had to access a WebDriver WebElement object directly using firstElement:

```
def categoryItem = $("div.category-item-title", text: categoryName).firstElement()
```

Then the Actions object can be used to add control-click actions:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver)
actions = actions.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
actions = actions.click(categoryItem)
actions = actions.keyUp(Keys.CONTROL)
actions.perform()
```

Note this code is within an instance method of a page object.

Here is the same code using the 'interact' mechanism erdi mentioned:

```
interact {
    keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
    click($("div.category-item-title", text: categoryName))
    keyUp(Keys.CONTROL)
}
```

Comment: Please note that Geb aids you in making your proposed solution even simpler - check out manual section about [interact closure](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/navigator.html#drag_and_drop)

Comment: Moving that documentation so it's not hidden under section "drag and drop" could help save others' time.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, we already have a ticket for that: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEB-207